# User role not working M2 Enterprse

Tags: magento2, orders, permissions, user-roles

My website has many store view like french,uk,german. I have created user for all the store view and assign resources to them. But when I login in admin panel with german user, I can see all the resources there but my orders are not there.

If I login with admin credentials then I can see all the orders for german store view but If login with german user only can see Order tab not orders

I am using Enterprise editon there we have Role Scope, we can use the store view there

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you cannot create a user role for a specific storeview.

Anyway, I suggest you check your user roles again. I assume the user role isn't properly configured.

Comment: User role is fine, on stagging server everything works but on production am getting only test order not the real orders, that created after we launched

Comment: you can create a user role for a specific storeview. this is an enterprise feature

Comment: Sort off, we have Role Scopes where we can define store view

Comment: @PhilippSander oh, I only have experience with the Commercial Edition.